# L. Gegenbauer's proof of Infinitude of Primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

I was going through the paper 'Euclid’S theorem on the infinitude of primes: A historical survey of its proofs' by Romeo Mestrovic where he mentioned that 
L. Gegenbauer proved Infinitude of Primes by means of the series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ n^s}$,(p-$20$) which is the claim of Dickson taken from his book 'History of the theory of numbers, volume I, Divisibility and Primality ' (p-$413$). They both referred to the following paper which I am unable to find from internet.

L. Gegenbauer, Note ¨uber die Anzahl der Primzahlen, Sitzungsber, SBer. Kais. Akad. Wissensch. Wien (Math.) 95, II (1887), 94–96; 97, Abt.IIa (1888), 374–377.

I asked this question in the following [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706181/unable-to-find-certain-paper) but the paper attached there is a paper of of Riemann,not of Gegenbauer.

I will be highly grateful if someone explain the proof mentioned in this paper or at least mention the source where I can find it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So you have now posted the same question twice, right? That's no good.

Comment: Actually I am not quite familiar with the rules and norms of this website. I am learning gradually. And I posted it because that question was not very well framed and was answered wrongly there. I am sorry if I broke any rule to this site .

Comment: When a question is answered incorrectly, you point out that the answer is incorrect, and wait for a correct answer. Think about what this website would look like, if everyone who posted a question, posted multiple copies of it.

Comment: i will take care of those things from next time.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362252/l-gegenbauers-proof-of-infinitude-of-primes

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sitzungsberichte_der_Mathematisch_Naturw/Huc5AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1 -- I was able to see the first paper there, on pages 94-96.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there are only finitely many primes. Then the Euler product in
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\zeta(2)=\prod_{p\in \Bbb P}\frac{p^2}{p^2-1}
$$
is rational, so that $\pi^2$ is rational. This is a contradiction.

Comment: I was asking for the proof what Gegenbauer exactly did.

Comment: I am aware of the proof you mentioned.

Comment: So he didn't do this? I am sorry. This is the most likely argument involving $\zeta(s)$. Let me check Gegenbauer.

Comment: Yeah..I know..but I am curious to know the exact proof done by Gegenbauer.

Comment: I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706181/unable-to-find-certain-paper). But the paper linked is indeed the one by Riemann :)

Comment: Yeah. That question is also asked by me.

Comment: Well, if you don't find it online, go to a library. They start to be open again now, I think.

Comment: Which library are you referring to?

Comment: At a university in your neighbourhood, or online at any university (faculty for mathematics).